# How to make an animated circular progress button for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, material-design

How can I make a Progress Button like the one in the below GIF in Android? I searched a lot, but I couldn't find anything exactly like this:

[image: Animated Progress Button]

This button is so pretty and I really want to be able to create a Progress Button exactly like this one. Any help or links to GitHub projects would be nice.

Comment: I just go github and found this less than in one minute : [Circular progress button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button) Also this too [Fab Progress](https://github.com/ckurtm/FabButton)

Comment: Its not different my friend , i have open eyes. First of all you have a button and one anim. When you click button you can hide and set visible fab progress and once it finished you can again set visible. Noone can help you directly. Please do some effort and come here with some of code of what you tried. I show you one way and you can try it.Stackoverflow exists for that purpose

Comment: What about converting rectangle button to circular button anim?

Comment: yes there is another way too. We can talk about possibilities. But if you choose one way and try to it. Then come with your code you can get exact answers . also if you checkout my first comment . You should see "circular progress button" link. If you go there and watch demo you can see that anim which you talking about !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the GitHub link to use this.

[LoadToast](https://github.com/code-mc/loadtoast)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. realy nice. tnx

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly [FabButton](https://github.com/ckurtm/FabButton) what you looking for

```
<view
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        class="mbanje.kurt.fabbutton.FabButton"
        android:id="@+id/determinate"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:color="#ff6e9cff"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_play"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        app:fbb_autoStart="true"
        app:fbb_progressColor="#ff170aff"
        app:fbb_progressWidthRatio="0.1"
        app:fbb_endBitmap="@drawable/ic_fab_complete"
        app:fbb_showEndBitmap="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a circular seekbar and when the seekBar progress is 100, you can change the image from cross (x) to tick. To implement circular progress bar you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the Blog the image comes from](http://materialdesignblog.com/material-design-concept-of-animated-progress-fab-button/).

It references [another article on that same blog](http://materialdesignblog.com/awesome-css-codepen-to-enhance-material-design-fab-button/) about FAB (`Floating Action Button`) design, which includes code samples, examples, and codepen links.

Comment: I cant see any code or example in his website. Where is codes?

Comment: The second link in my answer contains CodePen boxes, with tabs to show HTML, CSS, and output.

Comment: I need Android codes not CSS. TY